# Combine two jQuery hover scripts

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

For a portfolio I created an entry with a picture and a caption with additional subtext.
When hovering over the image, the image changes from grayscale to color (css image replacement).
When hovering over the caption, it slides up and reveals a subtext.

I would like to combine these two functions. When I hover anywhere on the entry, I would the picture to change from grayscale to color and the subtext to slide up.

I set up a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blendwerk/q8HtS/

How can I achive my goal. I appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/q8HtS/3/

You just need to attach mouse events on whole area with picture and text, and for insurance to rebind event you can set a namespace to rebind them separatly in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding just one hover event to the wrapping div, like this

http://jsfiddle.net/C8yV7/

Note you might also need to restrict the size of the div, which is currently 100% of the page width

Comment: Actually, there are more divs surrounding image-wrapper. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the desired effect:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fadeimg").find(".spanimg").hide();
    $(".fadesub").find(".spansub").hide();

    $(".fadeimg").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find(".spanimg").stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).next().find(".spansub").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find(".spanimg").stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).next().find(".spansub").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
        }
    );
     $(".fadesub").hover(
         function() {
            $(this).find(".spansub").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
            $(this).prev().find(".spanimg").stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
         }, 
         function() {
            $(this).find(".spansub").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
            $(this).prev().find(".spanimg").stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000);
         }
     );
});
```